# Can I use puphpet files to deploy a vps server without vagrant

Tags: vagrant, vps, puppet

I'm using puphpet/vagrant in local to work with symfony but I wanted to know if I can use puphpet's scripts/files to deploy it on my vps server if Im using the same OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually use a Vagrant plugin to connect to any server you have SSH access to. It works exactly the same way the Digital Ocean, Rackspace, AWS, etc providers do, but it simply cannot create or destroy the machine. Use this plugin: https://github.com/tknerr/vagrant-managed-servers